# Installing AWS elasticbeanstalk command line tool in ubuntu:error The 'awsebcli==3.10.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to install AWS elasticbeanstalk command line tool in my ubuntu machine

Installed with  `pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli`

But when i try to get the eb version with `eb --version` i got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/shamon/.local/bin/eb", line 6, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   2927, in 
>       @_call_aside   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   2913, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   635, in _build_master
>       ws.require(**requires**)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   943, in require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   829, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'awsebcli==3.10.0'
>   distribution was not found and is required by the application

Comment: any solution so far?

Comment: @Marcel solved the issue:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally  i resolved the issue.

First upgrade the `pip` and then `pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli`.